# Multiply variable by another variable and then format it as a string

Tags: terraform

Could I multiply variable by another variable in Terraform?

This seems to work:

```
count = "${var.var1} *  ${var.var2}"
```

I then tried:

```
count = "${format("int","${var.var1}" * "${var.var2}")}"
```

when var1 =0 and var2 = 0.

But this then throws the following error error:

> cannot parse "int%!(EXTRA int=0)" as an integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually specify the placeholder for your integer to be interpolated into. [`format`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#format-format-args-) uses the `printf` style syntax that is documented [here](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).

So in your case you could do something like:

```
variable "var1" {
  default = 1
}

variable "var2" {
  default = 2
}

output "example" {
  value = "${format("int-%d", var.var1 * var.var2)}"
}
```

This will output:

```
example = int-2
```

Running `$ TF_VAR_var1=10 TF_VAR_var2=42 terraform apply` will output:

```
example = int-420
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to multiply two numbers as in your example is as follows:

```
count = "${var.var1 * var.var2}"
```

Notice that the multiplication operator goes inside the `${` `}` expression delimiters, because it's part of the expression. If you put the `*` outside then it is taken as a literal string, producing a result like `"2 * 2"` rather than `"4"`.

To produce a string like `int-4` (that is, to place a prefix on the front), place that prefix outside of the delimiters:

```
example = "int-${var.var1 * var.var2}"
```

Any `${` ... `}` sequence inside quotes is replaced by the result of evaluating the expression inside the delimiters. Anything outside of those delimiters is taken literally.